# Opencart about double url

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, opencart

I have an Opencart site and I have turned on SEO (search engine optimization)  Urls in the Settings to make my URLs SEO friendly.

And I get friendly url `www.mydomainname.com/productname-341` 
which is ok.

But how to disable

`www.mydomainname.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=341`?

Now I can access the same page with two different urls:

`www.mydomainname.com/productname-341`

and

`www.mydomainname.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=341`

Is it possible to make some code in `htaccess` if somebody types in the url `index.php?*` to redirect them to `www.mydomainname.com`?

Comment: provide your .htaccess rules

Comment: I don't have any rules for this

Comment: I find maybe a find the solutions can somebody please tell me if this is correct?

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=product/product&product_id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.mydomainname.com/? [R=301,L]

Comment: Can you please elaborate that?